# empty input validation not worked?

Tags: javascript

I made a simple calculator   with javascript , but when i want to validate input , it
display Nan, and if statement not worked to validate empty input  ?  How to fix this and how to validate empty input by this form   and  how  to  remove the Nan Text displayed after empty input submit ?

```js
let b = document.querySelector("#submit");
b.addEventListener("click", function() {

let c = document.querySelector("#plus").value;
let d = document.querySelector("#minus").value;
let result = document.querySelector(".result");
 let output = parseInt(c) + parseInt(d);
result.innerHTML = output;
if(c.value == ""  && d.value == "") {
console.log("Wrong");
}

else {
console.log("Well Typed");
}
}
)
```

```css
body {
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 background-color:white;
 justify-content:center;
 font-family:"Montserrat",sans-serif;
 flex-direction:column;
}
button {
  background-color:#232324;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 17px;
}


.result {
width:50%;
min-height:50px;
background-color:transparent;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction:row;
}

input {
margin: 20px 0;
padding:10px;
color:black;
background-color:lightgray;
border:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="number" placeholder = ""id  = "plus">
<input type="number" id  = "minus">
<div class="row">
<button id="submit">
+
</button>
<button id="submit">
-
</button>
<button id="submit">
x
</button>
<button id="submit">
÷
</button>
</div>

<span class="result">1</span>
</body>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/albenoo/8zwya2c9/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let b = document.querySelector("#submit");
b.addEventListener("click", function() {

let c = document.querySelector("#plus").value;
let d = document.querySelector("#minus").value;
let result = document.querySelector(".result");
let output = parseInt(c) + parseInt(d) || "";

if(c == ""  && d == "") {
  console.log("Wrong");
}else {
  console.log("Well Typed");
}
  result.innerHTML = output;

})
```

```css
body {
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 background-color:white;
 justify-content:center;
 font-family:"Montserrat",sans-serif;
 flex-direction:column;
}
button {
  background-color:#232324;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 17px;
}


.result {
width:50%;
min-height:50px;
background-color:transparent;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction:row;
}

input {
margin: 20px 0;
padding:10px;
color:black;
background-color:lightgray;
border:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="number" placeholder = ""id  = "plus">
<input type="number" id  = "minus">
<div class="row">
<button id="submit">
+
</button>
<button id="submit">
-
</button>
<button id="submit">
x
</button>
<button id="submit">
÷
</button>
</div>

<span class="result">1</span>
</body>
```

Comment: this is what i'm looking for, thank you so much for the help

Comment: Why would you still calculate the output even tho the user input isn't correct?

Comment: @0stone0, the calculations already made outside the condition, I just rendered the output value that reflects the expected result. when user input then renders it, and when there is no input just show nothing, I think that makes more sense

Comment: no , i want only calculate  two input values  to display on output, but i want to add an if else when user dont write any number, you solved this btw thanks for this help

Comment: @AlbenisKërqeli, I got your point, I updated the solution to only render one output and left the condition to handle only the console messages.

Answer (score 1):

The following line already gets the `value` of the `#plus` element.

```
let c = document.querySelector("#plus").value;
```

Therefore, in the `if()` statement, there is no need to call `.value` again;

```
# wrong
if(c.value == ""  && d.value == "") {

#improved
if(c == "" || d == "") {
```

---

*Improved Code Snippet*;

```js
let b = document.querySelector("#submit");
b.addEventListener("click", function() {

    let c = document.querySelector("#plus").value;
    let d = document.querySelector("#minus").value;

    if (c == "" || d == "") {
        console.log("Wrong");
    } else {
        console.log("Well Typed");
        let result = document.querySelector(".result");
        let output = parseInt(c) + parseInt(d);
        result.innerHTML = output;
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    background-color:white;
    justify-content:center;
    font-family:"Montserrat",sans-serif;
    flex-direction:column;
}
button {
    background-color:#232324;
    border:none;
    color:white;
    padding:10px 17px;
}

.result {
    width:50%;
    min-height:50px;
    background-color:transparent;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:row;
}

input {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding:10px;
    color:black;
    background-color:lightgray;
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <input type="number" placeholder="" id="plus">
    <input type="number" id="minus">
    <div class="row">
        <button id="submit">
            +
        </button>
        <button id="submit">
            -
        </button>
        <button id="submit">
            x
        </button>
        <button id="submit">
            ÷
        </button>
    </div>
    <span class="result">1</span>
</body>
```

---

Small notes;

- I've changed the `&&` (and) to `||` (or) since 1 empty input should be 'invalid'
- HTML id's are unique, you can't have multiple `<button id="submit">` ([Read more info](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp))

Comment: thanks so much for this, any idea how to remove nan result when input are empty submitted?

Comment: @AlbenisKërqeli You should not calculate and add the result to the `output` element if the user input isn't valid. I've place that code inside the ifstatement so it wont be executed if the user input is invalid

Comment: ok i will fix , it, and i  will change  ids to classes

Answer (score 1):

```js
let b = document.querySelector("#submit");
b.addEventListener("click", function() {

  let c = document.querySelector("#plus").value;
  let d = document.querySelector("#minus").value;
  
  if(c !== "" && d !== ""){
    let result = document.querySelector(".result");
    let output = parseInt(c) + parseInt(d);
    result.innerHTML = output;
      console.log("Well Typed");
  }
  else{
     console.log("Wrong");
  }
}
)
```

```css
body {
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 background-color:white;
 justify-content:center;
 font-family:"Montserrat",sans-serif;
 flex-direction:column;
}
button {
  background-color:#232324;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 17px;
}


.result {
width:50%;
min-height:50px;
background-color:transparent;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction:row;
}

input {
margin: 20px 0;
padding:10px;
color:black;
background-color:lightgray;
border:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="number" placeholder = ""id  = "plus">
<input type="number" id  = "minus">
<div class="row">
<button id="submit">
+
</button>
<button id="submit">
-
</button>
<button id="submit">
x
</button>
<button id="submit">
÷
</button>
</div>

<span class="result">1</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a else if statement for this code
when the first input has value and the second input has no value
Any suggestions?

```js
if (c == "" && d == "") {
    console.log("Wrong");
    error.innerHTML = "<h1>Write Number Please>/h1> ";
  } 
  else if(c == "" && d >=0  ||  c>= 0 &&  d=="") {
  console.log("write value for all inputs");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Well Typed");
    result.innerHTML = output;
  }
})
```